# Inserting abstract{} changes margins of the page

Tags: margins, abstract

There is the template I have to use for a papaer and it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}  %%% for including graphics
\usepackage{url}       %%% for including URLs
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

\title{Example Paper for IWCS}
\date{}

\author{Example Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

But I have to insert an abstract and when I do it using `abstract{}` the margins of the page changes.
Any ideas how to have an abstract and maintain 2.5cm margins at the same time?

[image]

[image]

The minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}  %%% for including graphics
\usepackage{url}       %%% for including URLs
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

\title{This is the Title of the Paper}
\date{}
\author{Author Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\abstract{The term "domestic dog" is generally used for both of the domesticated and feral varieties. The English word dog comes from Middle English dogge, from Old English docga, a "powerful dog breed".[6] The term may possibly derive from Proto-Germanic *dukkōn, represented in Old English finger-docce ("finger-muscle").[7] The word also shows the familiar petname diminutive -ga also seen in frogga "frog", picga "pig", stagga "stag", wicga "beetle, worm", among others.[8] The term dog may ultimately derive from the earliest layer of Proto-Indo-European vocabulary, reflecting the role of the dog as the earliest domesticated animal.
}

\section{Introduction}
The term "domestic dog" is generally used for both of the domesticated and feral varieties. The English word dog comes from Middle English dogge, from Old English docga, a "powerful dog breed".[6] The term may possibly derive from Proto-Germanic *dukkōn, represented in Old English finger-docce ("finger-muscle").[7] The word also shows the familiar petname diminutive -ga also seen in frogga "frog", picga "pig", stagga "stag", wicga "beetle, worm", among others.[8] The term dog may ultimately derive from the earliest layer of Proto-Indo-European vocabulary, reflecting the role of the dog as the earliest domesticated animal.

\end{document}
```